# Setting different layouts in the same TabSpec - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

Inside a TabHost, I have 4 tabs, one of which is a LOG-IN tab. Depending on whether or not the user is logged in, this tab shows a layout containing a login form if the user is not logged in or otherwise sets the tab content layout to user details retrieved from MySQL database.

I have tried setting the layout using the simple "if-else" statement, but on loggin-in (trying to dynamically change the layout) the new layout replaces the TabHost altogether and my tabs are no longer visible.

How do I dynamically set the layout of a tab?